# Why didn't I get 'Nice Answer'?

Tags: support, badges, specific-question, nice-answer

I did not get a 'Nice Answer' for [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33333/why-downvote-a-user-with-no-points/33334#33334), is it disabled on meta, is it a bug, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: It's disabled for answers with less than 10 uptokes.

Comment: NICE ANSWER!!  There :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a Nice Answer for a question that has been downvoted or deleted and doesn't fit the criteria of Nice Answer anymore, you won't get a new one.

Comment: I didn't get downvotes once I passed 10 votes

Answer (score 4):

Because it wasn't good?...

...I think you did - You have 3x Nice answers and looking at your profile, you have 3 answers with over 10 up votes.

Just remember to wait patiently.

Comment: oh... so perhaps the notification is broken then