# Nice Answer — strange behavior?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, badges, nice-answer

In August I received the [Nice Answer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=413501) on a question which was subsequently deleled. The badge is still pointing to that question. Now, I guess, I [qualified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814706/self-tracking-entities-vs-poco-entities/3815968#3815968) for another Nice Answer badge. By reading the accepted answer in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33423/why-didnt-i-get-nice-answer), I understand that I will not get the second badge because the previous 'nice answer' is on a deleted question.

My question is why is the Nice Answer badge in my profile pointing to the old deleted question and not to the new 'live' question? Or did my answer violate some other rules (it was downvoted once but the downvote was reverted)?

**Edit:**

I'm resurrecting this question and changing main tag to Bug. Today I received Nice answer badge for the answer I mentioned in the former description. The reason probably is that today I received upvotes on my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326). It looks exactly like the behavior mentioned in the linked question (comment).

**Edit2:**

I hoped this will be solved by recalc but it didn't. The [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=413501) now points to: `Post is no longer availabe.` instead of to correct [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326).

Comment: Seems closely related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63514/badge-notification-targets-wrong-post-for-nice-answer-for-upvotes-to-old-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this was solved when we rewrote badges and the reason IDs were specific, meaning there is no longer 1 defunct entry based on counts, but 2 separate entries for the 2 badges now.

Sorry I forgot to update this!