# Did not receive 'Nice Answer' badge

Tags: support, badges, nice-answer

Not sure if this is a bug or I am just missing something but I did not receive a `Nice Answer` badge for the following question:

[Why does .NET add an additional slash to the already existent slashes in a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465923/why-does-net-add-an-additional-slash-to-the-already-existent-slashes-in-a-path/5465940#5465940)

It's been quite a while since the answer received the 10th up vote so is there something else that needs to happen?  I checked and others have received this badge recently so the process doesn't look broken.

**EDIT:**  I figured there had to be a good reason.  Is there any way to find out how many badges you are in the whole without looking at the history of every badge?

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33423/150235). Note that you have 8 +10 answers, and your profile currently shows 8 Nice Answer badges.

Comment: Just to confirm what 4 people have already mentioned, but your [Nice Answer badge list](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=8707) includes one "post no longer available", which basically is used to accomodate the recent instead of awarding a new badge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as if one of your previous 'Nice Answers' was deleted. It seems that you won't be awarded the badge for this answer, as the previous one hasn't been revoked.

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=8707

Comment: Which this being stated, should SO even allow you to delete a nice answer post?

Comment: It's not clear which was deleted; the answer or the question. If it was the question deleted, it wouldn't be fair to 'revoke' the badge, as it was genuinely earned.

Comment: The relevant answer is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656981/what-software-for-your-own-personal-use-did-you-write/657046#657046).

Comment: The link is now broken. The [original thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20090321082302/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656981) can be found on the Internet Archive.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you "owed" a nice answer badge already for an answer which previously gained you one, but which was either deleted or downvoted to under 10 votes.

Comment: Oops. I seem to have answered with *both* hands by accident.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Will the real Skeet please stand up?

Comment: I'm Jon Skeet, and so is my wife.

Comment: He's right, you know.

Comment: [You're guys all Rebecca Chernoff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85591/were-all-rebecca-chernoff-o). Or at least I think you are.

Answer (score 2):

You do have got nice answer badge in your profile.

Your profile says you have 8 nice answer badges and in your answer summary, it shows 8 answers which are voted 10 and above. So I think you do have got that badge.

Answer (score 2):

One of the answers you received the badge for has since been deleted (rather, the question that you answered has been deleted). Thus before this answer, you already had eight badges. Even though that question was deleted, you didn't lose the badge, but this means that you don't receive another 'nice answer' badge until you get a ninth 'nice answer'. This most recent one, in effect, replaces the badge you would have lost from the old question being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have 8 10+ vote answers and 8 Nice Answer badges. This appears to be the correct behavior.