# Missing "Nice Answer" badge from non-deleted answers

Tags: support, badges, nice-answer

I realize it's possible that a "nice answer" badge [will not be received if a previous nice answer has been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85662/did-not-receive-nice-answer-badge); but in any case, the number of applicable, non-deleted answers in the profile page should match the number of badges, shouldn't it?

Because [my profile page on gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/122/oak) lists 36 applicable answers but only 35 badges. I don't mean to be petty - some of those answers don't deserve those votes, anyway - I just want to point out a potential bug if it is one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contribution for "[What are some programming games that are out there?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/what-are-some-programming-games-that-are-out-there)" is listed with 14 votes in your profile and therefore looks like it would qualify for a Nice Answer badge. But actually those votes come from two answers to the same question (indicated by the "(2)" after the question name in the profile). The individual answers have only 8 and 6 votes.

So the badge count is accurate, it's only the profile that is a little confusing.

Comment: Ah, I see... thank you for clarifying.